# Roaming appdata for npm, too long path

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova, npm

I recently installed node.js and phonegap (phonegap is unrelated to the problem, it could be anything as you will see below). After that I started having troubles with my roaming profile in Windows: it would get stuck for a very long time, and then login with a "partially synced user profile".

Event log showed that it is because of the 256 limit in the path. One of the culprits:

```
[serverpath excluded for privacy.Its length is 38 characters]
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js
```

(Event code 1509, "The filename or extension is too long")

My options are pretty limited: I cannot change the server path, nor exclude my account from syncing.

Can I:

- change the storage location of npm data?
- move the existing configuration to a different folder without breaking something?
- change the timeout time so that at least the profile "partly syncs" more quickly?

Setup: Windows 7 x86. Server is Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: I have the same issue but it doesn't have to deal with roaming, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731066/too-long-paths-because-of-nested-node-dependencies, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that might come across this:

A possible workaround that I ended up using, is to exclude the specified subfolder (in my case, AppData\Roaming\npm) from the profile syncing.

This can be accomplished by editing the "Exclude directories in roaming profile" setting in group policy.

More info can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814592