# Too long paths because of nested node dependencies

Tags: node.js, path, npm

I'm using npm to install dependencies. After I have installed those, I want to share my project with someone who is not technical, and doesn't have npm, so I want to ship the node_modules inside the app.

However, because node nests the dependencies, it creates a file that has a very long path (217 characters)

```
node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\string_decoder\build\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\htmlparser2\node_modules\domhandler\test\cases\04-unescaped_in_script.json
```

The problem (on windows) is that when the end users tries to copy/paste the folder with too long filenames, he gets the following error:

[image]

Is it for example possible to tell npm to install the dependencies in a folder called `nm`
, so that the problem would more likely not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To circumvent the problem, I would try:

1. Mapping the path to a virtual drive. If it's a network-shared
       folder, you can use "Tools->Map Network drive", if not, you can use
       the "subst" command. More info here:
       http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-map-a-local-windows-folder-to-a-drive-letter/
2. Since the problem is just copying a set of folder, why not try
           Robocopy? It has support for longer filepaths than the native
           Windows Explorer.

Comment: Well, thing is that I can't use the robocopy command because I expect the main user to copy paste, and he won't type that command.

Comment: but he can double click a prepared .bat file that you have created with the command, can't he?

Comment: Well, he could but then I would prefer to create an installer.

Answer (score 3):

The situation has gone better with upcoming npm 3. Earlier I had to develop close to the root folder of the drive (c:\GH), but npm 3 has a more flat hierarchy. In a very rare circumstances, there might be a really long path name. That would happen if there are version conflicts and npm would have to install a package in a sub-folder instead of the node_modules root.

Shameless plug: I wrote [a blog post](http://www.triplet.fi/blog/npm-3-will-bring-brighter-future-for-windows-users/) about the problem & solution

Comment: I also found this suggestion for using the `rimraf` module useful forgetting out of the mess created by npm's less than 3.x on Windows. Much thanks, Tx3!